# UITableViewRowAction - keeping the cell's text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using `UITableViewRowAction` is great.
One thing that bugs me, I would like to keep part of the original cell `textLabel` so that my dear users will know what they are deleting.

By using `UITableViewRowAction` it pushes the cell label out of the screen,  (see "MY TEXT?" in green)

**Any way around this?**

[image]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Edit") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
            //TODO: edit the row at indexPath here
        }
        editAction.backgroundColor = .gray

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
            //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

        let sendAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
            //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
        }
        sendAction.backgroundColor = .darkGray

        return [deleteAction,editAction,sendAction]
    }
```

Comment: That's normal API behaviour you can't change it. You can go with custom swipe as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your labelText to stay as it is, you must add a button for delete, becouse you can not change this.